# Problema al inicializa datepicker JS

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Estoy con un pequeño problema que no he podido solucionar, estoy inicializando un `datepicker` en boostrap con cierta fecha, que se extrae de un servicio, pero hasta ahora no he logrado poder hacer... (Anteriormente me funcionaba pero para un dateRangePicker y ahora lo cambie por problemas con los modales)

```
fechaIni    = result[0].fech_inicio;
fechaFin    = result[0].fech_termino;

FechaInicioModal(fechaIni);
$('#fechaInicioProfe').data('datepicker').setStartDate("\""+fechaIni+"\"");

FechaTermino(fechaFin,1);
$('#fechaTerminoProfe').data('datepicker').setStartDate("\""+fechaFin+"\"");
```

al hacer su respectivo console.log me arroja las fechas correspondientes:

> fechaIni = 01/01/2020
>
> fechaFin = 01/12/2020

y el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined








function FechaInicioModal(fechaIni) {
    var date    = new Date();
    var anho    = date.getFullYear()+1;
    if(fechaIni == null){
        fechaIni == '01/01/'+ anho;
    }

    $("#fechaInicioProfe").datepicker({
        startDate : '01/01/',
        endDate : '31/12/',
        minDate : '01/01/1930',
        maxDate : '31/12/',
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
    //  yearRange : "1900:2100"
    }).val("");
}

function FechaTermino(fechaTermino,filtro) {
    var date    = new Date();
    var anho    = date.getFullYear()+1;
    var fechaIni= $("#fechaInicioProfe").val(); 
    if(filtro == 1){
        if(fechaTermino == null){
            fechaTermino = '01/12/'+ anho;
            fechaIni     = $("#fechaInicioProfe").val();
        }
    }
    else if(filtro >= 2){
        fechaIni     = $("#fechaInicioProfe").val();
    }

    $("#fechaTerminoProfe").datepicker({
        startDate           :   fechaTermino,
        endDate             :   '31/12/'+ anho,
        minDate             :   fechaIni,
        maxDate             :   '31/12/'+ anho,
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        //yearRange : "1900:2100"
    }).val("");
    if(filtro == 3){
        $('#fechaTerminoProfe').data('datepicker').setStartDate("\""+fechaTermino+"\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: puedes colocar las funciones `FechaInicioModal` y `FechaTermino` para saber como esta inicializando el datepicker.

Comment: Listo @OrlandoDeLaRosa

Comment: El datepicker que utilizas es el de [jQueryui](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) o el de [bootstrap](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Exacto tenia la misma pregunta de @OrlandoDeLaRosa que datepicker

Comment: es Boostrap....

Comment: Si fechaIni es string pk estableces la fecha de esta manera .setStartDate("\""+fechaIni+"\"");??? deberia ser .setStartDate(fechaIni);

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Tampoco lo toma con setStartDate(fechaIni);

Comment: Dado que las fechas están en formato `dd/mm/yyyy`, es posible que tengas que usar `format`: algo así:  `$("#fechaTerminoProfe").datepicker({
        startDate           :   fechaTermino, format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', ...` [Ver aquí](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) para más detalles.

Comment: @A.Cedano no funcionó tampoco